# PHP get clientID from database using session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a Log in page and when user logs in successfully it is brought to the welcome page and then he can click to book activity. When user clicks to book activity, calender appears with all activities that could be booked. When user clicks to book certain activity clientEvent table should be updated with clientID that should be taken from log in page and activityEventID. But I get an Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fitnessconnect`.`clientevent`, CONSTRAINT `clientevent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`activityEventID`) REFERENCES `activityevent` (`activityEventID`))

I am not sure where I'm making the mistake, if I do not get the clientID correctly from the log in page or something else.

Also I'm not sure how to pass the activityEventID  a href='CreateNewActivityBooking.php?activityEventID=activityEventID'
 I have used this but I'm not sure if its right

To create two tables i used this

```
 create table activityEvent
 (
   activityEventID integer auto_increment,
   date date,
   title varchar(30),
   description varchar(50),
   price integer,
   location varchar(30),
   startTime time,
   endTime time,
   activityTitle varchar(30),
   noOfPlaces integer,
   restricted varchar(30),
   personalTrainer_CoachID integer,
    primary key (activityEventID),
   foreign key (personalTrainer_CoachID) references personalTrainer_Coach(personalTrainer_CoachID)
   );

create table clientEvent
(
  clientEventID integer auto_increment,
  activityEventID integer,
  clientID integer,
  primary key (clientEventID),
  foreign key (activityEventID) references activityEvent(activityEventID),
  foreign key (clientID) references client(clientID)
 );
```

This is login.html

```
 <HTML>

  <BODY>

        <FORM action='login.php' method = 'POST'>
         <label>Enter your username</label>
         <input name="username" type="text"/>
         <br/>
         <label>Enter your password</label>
         <input name="password" type="password"/>
         <br/>
         <input type="submit"/>
     </FORM>

  </BODY>


  </HTML>
```

Login.php

```
<?php

   session_start();


   $userName = $_POST['username'];
   $passWord = $_POST['password'];

   require('connection.php');


    $dbpwd="";
    $con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);

 $sql ="select clientID, password from client where userName = '$userName'";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
    $dbpwd =$row['password'];

    $clientID =$_SESSION['clientID'];
    $_SESSION['clientID']='$clientID';


}

   if($dbpwd == $passWord)
 {


     header("Location: welcome.html");

 }
 else
 {
    echo"Passwords do not match";
    echo"</br>";
    echo"Please Try Again";


  }

  ?>
```

welcome.html this is only the start it does not have much functionality

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title> Welcome </title>
   </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Welcome!</h1>

     <button onClick="window.location='calendarTest2.php';" > Book   Activity</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

calenderTest2.php

```
<?php


   $monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May",  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
 ?>

 <?php
  if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"]))
      $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
   if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"]))
      $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
 ?>
 <?php
    $cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
    $cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
    $prev_year = $cYear;
    $next_year = $cYear;
    $prev_month = $cMonth-1;
    $next_month = $cMonth+1;
    if ($prev_month == 0 )
      {
            $prev_month = 12;
            $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
      }
    if ($next_month == 13 )
      {
         $next_month = 1;
         $next_year = $cYear + 1;
      }

     require("BookingsDB.php");
     $myBookingsDB = new BookingsDB();
     $bookings = $myBookingsDB->getMonthlyBookings($cMonth,$cYear);


    ?>
    <div align="left">
    <table width="400" border="5" align="left" id="calendar">
    <tr align="center">
    <td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><table width="100%" border="0"
    cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="50%" align="left"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
      . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>"
     style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
    <td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
    . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>"
     style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td align="center"><table width="100%" border="2" cellpadding="2"
      cellspacing="2">
      <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong> <?php
      echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
       <strong>S</strong></td>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
       <strong>M</strong></td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
       <strong>T</strong></td>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
        <strong>W</strong></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
        <strong>T</strong></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
        <strong>F</strong></td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
      <strong>S</strong></td>
   </tr>


 <?php

    require("connection.php");

    $con=mysqli_connect("$mysql_host","$mysql_user","$mysql_password","$mysql_database");

   // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


   $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
   $maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
    $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
     $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
     $today = getdate();


     for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++)
     {
       if(($i % 7) == 0 )
    {
        echo "<tr> ";
    }

  if($i < $startday)
   {
     echo "<td></td> ";
   }
  else
  {
      $day = $i - $startday + 1;
      $thisDate = new DateTime("$cYear-$cMonth-$day");
     $jsEvent[] = "document.getElementById('trigger" . $i . "').onclick =  function() {showForm()};";
      echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><a href='CreateNewActivityBooking.php?activityEventID=activityEventID' id='trigger" . $i . "'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>";



     foreach ($bookings as $key => $value)
       {

         if ($thisDate->format('Y-m-d') == $value['date']->format('Y-m-d'))
         {

            echo " ";
            echo $value['title'];
            echo " ";
            echo $value['startTime'];
        }

 }

     echo "</td>";

 }
  if(($i % 7) == 6 )
   {
       echo "</tr> ";
   }
  }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 <?php foreach($jsEvent as $event)
  {
      echo $event;
   }

  ?>

    function showForm()
   {
      document.getElementById('timeslots').style.display="block";
   };
   </script>
   </table></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

BookingsDB.php

```
<?php

session_start();



class BookingsDB
{
  private $bookings = array();
  private $con;

 public function BookingsDB()
  {
      require("connection.php");
      $this->con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);

  }

 public function getMonthlyBookings($thisMonth,$thisYear)
 {
     $sql = "SELECT activityEventID,date,title,startTime  FROM activityEvent WHERE YEAR(date) = $thisYear AND MONTH(date) = $thisMonth";
     $result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {

        $this->bookings[] = array('date'=>new DateTime($row['date']), 'title'=>$row['title'],'startTime'=>$row['startTime']);

        //$activityEventID =$_SESSION['activityEventID'];
        //$_SESSION['activityEventID']='activityEventID';

    }
    return $this->bookings;
}

  public function close()
  {
       mysqli_close($this->con);
   }

 }

 ?>
```

CreateNewActivityBooking.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require("connection.php");


$con=mysqli_connect("$mysql_host","$mysql_user","$mysql_password","$mysql_database");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$clientID=$_SESSION['clientID'];
$activityEventID =$_SESSION['activityEventID'];

$sql="Insert into clientEvent(clientID, activityEventID)    Values('$clientID','$activityEventID')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

    }
   echo "1 record added";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, it seems like you are not storing your `activityEventID` in session variable. And you are trying to access it on CreateNewActivityBooking.php page, while inserting the event to "clientEvent" table.

Look at the following lines in your code:

```
$clientID=$_SESSION['clientID'];
$activityEventID =$_SESSION['activityEventID']; //Here $_SESSION['activityEventID'] doesn't exists
```

As "clientEvent" table has foreign key constraint for "activityEventID" column. As this constrain will fail, the query will not be executed and you are getting the error.

So basically you need to find a way to pass correct value there.

Edit: As for your comment, the script that you posted doesn't seem to store 'activityEventID' in the session as the lines you quoted are actually commented on the script that you posted in question.

To be specific here is what you need to do.

On BookingsDB.php

```
$this->bookings[] = array('date'=>new DateTime($row['date']), 'title'=>$row['title'],'startTime'=>$row['startTime'], 'activityEventID'=>$row['activityEventID']);
```

And on your calenderTest2.php

```
echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>";
foreach ($bookings as $key => $value)
{

         if ($thisDate->format('Y-m-d') == $value['date']->format('Y-m-d'))
         {
            echo "<a href='CreateNewActivityBooking.php?activityEventID=".$value['activityEventId']."' id='trigger" . $i . "'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>";
            echo " ";
            echo $value['title'];
            echo " ";
            echo $value['startTime'];
        }

 }
echo '</td>';
```

So now you are passing activityEventID in query string for each link. And you can retrieve this in CreateNewActivityBooking.php as following:

`$activityEventID =$_GET['activityEventID'];`

You may need to reformat few things layout wise, but I think this is how it should be done.

Comment: I'm fairly new at this so am i not storing activityEventID on these lines in BookingDB.php ? @Vivek              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

              $this->bookings[] = array('date'=>new DateTime($row['date']),'title'=>$row['title'],'startTime'=>$row['startTime']);

           $activityEventID =$_SESSION['activityEventID'];
           $_SESSION['activityEventID']='activityEventID';

         }